# Read excel file without using module

Tags: perl, excel

Can I read an excel file without using any module?
I tried like just reading a normal file and it printed binary characters; maybe because of encoding?

But reading csv files is working normally.

Comment: Sure, change the extension of the module from .pm to .pl, and there you go.

Comment: I know I can use many perl modules to read excel files. I wanted to know if I could do it without using them. I avoid modules, whenever I can.

Comment: Yeah, modules are nothing but trouble. There's no sense in reusing code tested and put through scrutiny by the Perl community when you can write your own.

Comment: Not sure why people down-vote, if they do not know the answer or if they see someone think differently than what they do.

Comment: Instead of using a 'module', you could use a 'utility' to convert the file to text. Just don't look under the hood, because that utility might be using a module of some sort.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Excel files are binary files, and the format of the pre-2007 ones is apparently quite hairy. I believe `.xlsx` files are actually zipped XML, so unzipping them should yield something human-readable, but I've never tried it. Why do you want to not use a module though?

Some further reading, if you're interested:

http://joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/02/19.html
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML_file_formats

Answer (score 6):

*Can I read an excel file without using any module?*

In theory yes. In practice no.

An Excel XLS file is a binary file within a binary file. The first step would be to parse the Excel BIFF data out of the OLE COM document container. This data isn't necessarily in sequential order.

Then you have to parse the Excel BIFF data, allowing for differences between versions, a shared string table with different encodings and CONTINUE blocks that map large data records in a parser unfriendly way.

The Excel XLSX format is a little easier since it is a collection of XML files in a Zip container. However, if you aren't using modules then even that would be a pain.

The Perl modules that deal with Excel files represent hundreds of man hours of work. Expect to invest a similar amount of work to avoid them.

Answer (score 5):

And why can't you use modules?

You can try figuring out the format of what an Excel spreadsheet looks like, code for that, and then use that in your program. Maybe write it as a module and submit it to CPAN. *Wait a second!* There's already a module like that there!

The whole purpose of CPAN is to prevent you from having to reinvent the wheel. You need to read an Excel spreadsheet, and someone has done the hard work to figure out how to do this, and is giving it to you free of charge. A $40,000 value<sup>1</sup>, and it's yours for free! The CPAN system makes installing modules fairly simple. You run the `cpan` command. There's no real reason to avoid modules that can save you hundreds of hours of work.

And, what type of modules do you *avoid*? Is it all modules, or is it only modules that are not included in the standard distribution. I hate to think you don't use things like `File::Copy` or `Data::Dumper` just because they're modules even though they're included by default in most Perl distributions.

---

<sup>1</sup> Imagine hiring a team to write code to convert an Excel file, so it can be read by a Perl program. They'd have to figure the ins and outs of the file format, code for all sorts of edge cases, and run it through all sorts of tests to make sure it really works. A rough estimate if we don't include things like charts, embedded content, and remote data access would be about 200 man-hours, but only because it's actually has been documented.

Comment: From your long answer, I understand your frustration about my question. I did not say I don't use modules anywhere. For instance, I would use `WWW::Mechanize` to automate websites, but I would prefer `system("cp $file1 $file2")` than `File::Copy`, because the former is more understandable to layman and easy to write. So here also, I just wanted to know if there is some easy way to read excel files, else I will settle with the perl modules which offer that functionality.

Comment: @cppcoder You are saying "understandable to layman"... Writeexcel module is very easy to understand and powerful as well ... Still choice is yours :)

Comment: Please, stop propogating the myth that Excel BIFF files are not documented by Microsoft, the full specification for all Office file formats (both BIFF and OfficeOpenXML) has been publicly available on the web for nearly 10 years now

Comment: @cppcoder: your thoughts are backwards. Embedding code in one language into a program written in another is always a bad idea, and only worthwhile if the payoff is substantial. If you don't like Perl then write everything in shell script, but embedding shell script into Perl is far from being *more understandable*. Surely you can't really believe that `system("cp $file1 $file2")` is clearer than `copy($file1, $file2)`?

Comment: @cppcoder - There are security concerns with using the `system` command. What if I wrote my own `cp` command, and had your program execute that? I've used that trick many times to get around security blockages. Don't use `system` when you can use Perl's own abilities.

Comment: @David W - I don't think it matters much. What if, I create a file `$myvirus` and used your program with `File::Copy` to do `copy($myvirus, $homepathofdavid)`?

Comment: @cppcoder We had a client who had another company do maint. on a massive program. Client wanted us to take over. Other company claimed the source was in propriety format, and thus we couldn't take over the account. I suspected their VCS was merely a GUI front to rcs, and they used a `system` call to call `rcs`. I wrote a program to print out the repo, and called it `rcs`. A call to their GUI ran my `rcs` which proved the repo was in RCS format. That company lost a $10 million annual contract due to that `system` command. When you use `system`, you lose control of your program.

Comment: Apart from the security issue, there's also the fact that `copy` is (presumably) cross-platform, whereas using `system` to call `cp` won't work on Windows, for example.